# Extract Age in numeric form from string format in r

Tags: r, string, numeric, data-conversion

I have a vector `Age` of strings which contains age of various subjects like this :

```
"1 Months8 Days"  "1 Years"         "10 Days"         "10 Months"       "10 Months1 Days"
```

Now, I want it to convert in a single number, which is equal to the age in years.
what can be the best way to do this?

I tried using :

```
regmatches(years, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", years))
```

But this doesn't differentiate between months and years. The vector doesn't have strings of any other format than presented above. How can this be done?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @ Roman Lustrik , the age in years

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution :

```
v <- c("1 Months8 Days", "1 Years","10 Days","10 Months","10 Months1 Days")

periods <- c(1, 1/12, 1/365)
names(periods) <- c('Years','Months','Days')
ages <- rep.int(0,length(v))
for(p in names(periods)){
  matches <- regmatches(v,gregexpr(paste0("[[:digit:]]+(?= ",p,")"), v,perl=TRUE))
  ages <- ages + sapply(matches,function(x) ifelse(length(x)== 0,0,as.numeric(x)*periods[p]))
}

> ages
[1] 0.10525114 1.00000000 0.02739726 0.83333333 0.83607306
```

Comment: This is significantly faster than using gsubfn.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a bit more convoluted way of using `gsub`. I had a problem with matching days and [@BhargavRao](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31026721#31026721), [@Cath and @Tensibai](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31026771#31026771) fixed it in chat.

```
x <- c("1 Months8 Days", "1 Years", "10 Days", "10 Months", "10 Months1 Days", "1 Months")

xy <- data.frame(
  original = x,
  years = as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(x, split = "Years"), FUN = function(m) gsub("\\d+$", "\\1", m))),
  months = as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(x, split = "Months"), FUN = function(m) gsub("\\d+$", "\\1", m)[1])),
  days = as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(x, split = "Days"), FUN = function(m) gsub("(.*?)(\\d\\d?)(\\s)$", "\\2", m)))
)

xy$result <- apply(xy[-1], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(m) sum(m["years"], m["months"]/12, m["days"]/365, na.rm = TRUE))

xy

         original years months days     result
1  1 Months8 Days    NA      1    8 0.10525114
2         1 Years     1     NA   NA 1.00000000
3         10 Days    NA     NA   10 0.02739726
4       10 Months    NA     10   NA 0.83333333
5 10 Months1 Days    NA     10    1 0.83607306
6        1 Months    NA      1   NA 0.08333333
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
v2 <- gsubfn("[A-Za-z]+", list(Years = "* 1", Months = "* 1/12", Days = "* 1/365"), 
           sub("(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])", " + ", v1, perl=TRUE))
unname(sapply(v2, function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
#[1] 0.10525114 1.00000000 0.02739726 0.83333333 0.83607306
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("1 Months8 Days", "1 Years", "10 Days", "10 Months", "10 Months1 Days")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for given format

```
> age<- c("1 Months8 Days", "1 Years", "10 Days", "10 Months", "10 Months1 Days")
> t <- regmatches(age, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", age))
> c_m <-  regexpr("Months" , age) > 0
> c_d <- regexpr("Days" , age) > 0
> i <- 1
> age_in_years <- sapply(t , function(x ){
+    if(length(x) >1){
+       a <- as.numeric(x[1])/12 + as.numeric(x[2]) / 360 }
+    else{ 
+       if(c_m[i]){
+          a <- as.numeric(x) / 12}
+       else if (c_d[i]){
+          a <- as.numeric(x)/360}
+       else{a<- as.numeric(x)} }
+    i <<- i +1
+    a})
> age_in_years
[1] 0.10555556 1.00000000 0.02777778 0.83333333 0.83611111
```

Comment: `t1` appears to be a stub.

Comment: but `10` and `10` describe Days and Months respectively. Maybe an `ifelse` statement?

Comment: edited the solution to include all the cases. Now I think it should work